# Android: Taking a picture using camera intent and saving it to a java.io.File

Tags: android, file, nullpointerexception, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I'm trying to get a picture from user and then send it to our server. I provide two options: choosing from gallery or taking a new picture using default camera in their phones.

Gallery thing works correctly, I can get the photo they selected and send it without any problem. But in camera option, camera opens, takes a picture, saves it on SD card with the location I specified, no problem, but when it returns back to my application, I always get a NullPointerException and my application is forced to close. Here is what I do:

```
private String tempFilePath = "";    
...
public void addPhotoUsingCamera() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    tempFilePath = getOutputMediaFilePath(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(tempFilePath)));     
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_ACTIVITY_CODE);
}
```

And then I use following to get the photo taken:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    ...
    case CAMERA_ACTIVITY_CODE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {         
            picture = new File(tempFilePath);
        }
        break;
    ...
    }
}
```

I also tried

```
Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photoTaken);
image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
```

inside `case CAMERA_ACTIVITY_CODE:` but no matter what I try I always get a NullPointerException in this part of code.

There is the logcat info where line 202 corresponds to `case CAMERA_ACTIVITY_CODE:` part.

```
01-31 23:40:13.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8009): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=101, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.ollaa.android/com.ollaa.android.share.ShareFinalScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException

01-31 23:40:13.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8009): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 23:40:13.154: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8009):     at com.ollaa.android.share.ShareFinalScreen.onActivityResult(ShareFinalScreen.java:202)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Note:** I have declared all necessary permissions in AndroidManifest related to camera and SD card.

**EDIT:** I realized that tempFilePath does not last until camera activity returns to my app. I put the initialization for tempFilePath in my `onCreate` method but this time picture is not set when I try to reach it from an outside function other than `onActivityResult`. I feel like I do not know Java at all, when we change a class variable within a function, the changed value should be visible from all functions of that class right??

Answer (score 2):

When using:

intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, myFile);

The file must exist on the 'disk'. The Camera Activity does not create it, which is IMHO a bug. So you have to use `myFile.createNewFile();`
Also, You have to send Camera Activity a file and not a path.

Try something like this:

```
 tempFilePath = getOutputMediaFilePath(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
 String fileName = "myPhoto";   
 File myFile = new File (tempFilePath,fileName); 
 myFile.createNewFile();   
 // at this point stop the debugger and check if the file exists on the 'disk'.  
 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(myFile)));
```

There may be a better way to do this without using `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`.  Maybe another user can help.

Also, note if the user presses cancel and does not take a picture you have to delete the file.

Note: I am using Android API 2.2.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but it did not make any difference. Thanks anyway :)